# Proof or confutation that a matrix is positive semidefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, positive-semidefinite

I know that if $x$ is a column vector in $\mathbb R^n$ then the matrix $xx^T$ is positive semidefinite. This is not difficult to prove (see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164224/in-what-spaces-are-outer-product-of-x-with-itself-positive-semidefinite)).

Now let $V$ be a real $n-$dimensional vector space with positive definite inner product $<*,*>$ and $x_k$ $(k=1,2, ... , n)$  $n$ vectors in $V$. Define the matrix $M$ whose elements are $m_{ij}=<x_i,x_j>$.

Is $M$ positive semidefinite? Could you please help me in the proof, if that is true, or to disprove if it is false?).

Comment: This is what is called a Gram matrix and it is positive semidefinite. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix

Comment: @Wintermute Thank you very much.

Comment: We don't usually require refutations to be "forceful" (what distinguishes a confutation from a refutation)...